# Truecrypt mounts an external harddrive volume on one system, but does not on another

Tags: external-hard-drive, mount, truecrypt, safe-mode

I have an encrypted external hard drive which I'm able to mount on my desktop.
However my laptop is in trouble and before handing it over to the lab, I'd like to back it up. Alas, Truecrypt won't mount the volume on the laptop. Instead I receive the following error:

```
Incorrect password or not a TrueCrypt volume.
```

Notice that I'm running my laptop in Win7's Safe Mode. Could that have anything to do with it?
What else could it be?

Comment: A few trivialities: 1) I need the backup to be encrypted 2) I re-checked the password several times 3) I can't start the laptop without safe-mode

Comment: Desktop TrueCrypt ver is 7.0a - Laptop TrueCrypt ver is 7.1a